# My AJAX request object doesn't properly resolve the protocol portion of the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, https

I'm trying to send an AJAX request from a secure page, but the XMLHttpRequest object doesn't properly resolve the protocol portion of the URL. This behavior is identical in Safari, Chrome, and Canary.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function sendGETRequest(url, params, callback) {
    "use strict";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status !== 200) {
                callback({ajaxError: true, status: req.status});
            } else {
                callback(req);
            }
        }
    };
    req.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    req.send();
}
```

Here are some different URLs passed to sendGETRequest(), along with their results:

```
url = "ajax/";
GET https://mydomain/mypage/ajax/?params 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

The above is the expected behavior: the relative url is correctly resolved with protocol intact.

```
url = "/ajax/";
The page at https://mydomain/mypage/ displayed insecure content from http://mydomain/ajax/?params.
```

Here, the realtive url is correctly appended to the domain root, but with the wrong protocol.

```
url = "https://mydomain/ajax/";
The page at https://mydomain/mypage/ displayed insecure content from http://mydomain/ajax/?params.
```

Here, the protocol is just ignored.

To be clear, I'm not trying to work around the same origin policy; I want to send an AJAX request from a secure page to a resource with the same (secure) origin. How can I accomplish this simple task?

Comment: what is happening on the server side? are you using apache with .htaccess rewrite rules?  I have a hunch the problem isn't the ajax, it's the server.  Unless, of course, you can show that the actual connection is *not* going over port 443, or your server logs show that http was requested.

Comment: In the second and third examples above, the browser never sends the request because the request violates the same origin policy. This issue doesn't involve the server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in WebKit. It's been fixed in Safari 5 for Lion but **not** Snow Leopard, and it's been fixed in Chrome but **not** Canary,... helluva a bug.

Comment: Do you have any links that can reference this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a conversation here about this topic: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/459071-ajax-https

One of the last posts states "Just to be absolutely unambiguous; XML HTTP requests work over https
exactly as they do over http. If they did not our QA department would
have said something by now as they test over https almost exclusively"

Perhaps the server is not using Https (ssl) at the point where the request is being made: `mydomain/ajax/`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTTP and HTTPS.  As you mentioned in a comment, the request is never being sent due to same-origin policy.  How can the request be using the wrong policy if the request is never sent?  What is confusing you is that whatever program/add-on/tool/etc that is generating the error message is showing "HTTP" instead of "HTTPS".  The request IS and ALWAYS respects HTTPS when HTTPS is set.

Your real issue is quite simply that you are violating cross-origin policy. See this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

You cannot go UP the directory tree, only down.  In the first example, you are requesting a subfolder. That's fine.  In the second and third examples, you are requesting a page from a parent directory (ie, instead of `https://mydomain/mypage/ajax/` you are asking for `https://mydomain/ajax/`.  You cannot make a request up a directory tree like that.

Either move your index page up to the root of the domain, or change the same-origin policy header being sent on the files, or make a sub directory on the server handle the request (you can use something like PHP's [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to just include the parent file).

Comment: This is an interesting theory. However, the Mozilla link clearly discusses file URIs. I'm dealing with HTTP URIs which have a different sent of considerations, so are likely to be different. See e.g. [MDN JavaScript same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), which implements a more conventional origin based on domain name, protocol, and port number.

Comment: Even in your own link: `Mozilla considers two pages to have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages.`  Is the page being loaded on an SSL connection?  If not, then this is your problem